# Call to undefined method HTML_neolegal::legals()

Tags: php

I converted successfully a Joomla-1 into PHP-5.6 except one component, which gives me this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method HTML_neolegal::legals() in ../administrator/components/com_neolegal/admin.neolegal.php on line 64

And line 58-65 contains:

```
// id := 1 (only one record)
function legals( $option ) {
    global $database;
    $id = 1;
    $row = new mosNeolegal ( $database );
    $row->load( $id );
    HTML_neolegal::legals( $row, $option );
}
```

I know it's because i use a to new PHP version, but i need a workaround for this. It's not possible to downgrade.

Comment: probably you should declare `static function legals`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are two functions with the same name "legals".
Try to find the legals function on the HTML_neolegal Class and change the function name to for example **legals_new**

then change the call to HTML_neolegal::**legals_new**( $row, $option )...